# How to find Facebook Custom API id

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api, ads-api

I've started working with the Facebook Ads API and can make an audience, campaign or adset fine over the API. 
I'm having trouble when I want to retrieve the ID of something I've created in order to do something with it. Can I get this over the API? Or is it something that I have to on site?

Ideally I'd be able to retrieve the newest audience just after creating it.

Comment: First of all, almost anything in Facebook's APIs that creates something, returns the id of the created object in the response. And secondly, check https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/v2.8 - f.e. the edges of the user object might be of interest.

Comment: Oh amazing. At the risk of sounding like an idiot how can I get and store what's returned?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Facebook provide an API id for each api call.
but you can save the api results to your data, and then reuse the data.